# SignalR Websocket Exception when closing client

Tags: c#, sockets, owin, signalr.client, signalr-2

When starting and stopping a SignalR client that is connected to a basic self hosted server like this:

```
async public void Start(string url)
{
    _connection = new HubConnection(url);
    _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("hubname");
    await _connection.Start().ContinueWith((task) => IsRunning = true);
}
public void Stop()
{
    _connection.Stop();
}
```

I get the following exception when calling the "Stop" method (including trace messages):

```
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(c75fe282-a86d-406a-935b-5981b47bd472)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0 is New.
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : Abort(1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : End(1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket(1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0)
App.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Error while closing the websocket: System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.WebSocketConnection.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<WriteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.<<CloseAsync>b__6>d__8.MoveNext()
App.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Error while closing the websocket: System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.WebSocketConnection.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<WriteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.<<CloseAsync>b__6>d__8.MoveNext()
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (1bdabc19-e0a7-4649-aabb-bade071ad6d0)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(c75fe282-a86d-406a-935b-5981b47bd472)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(c75fe282-a86d-406a-935b-5981b47bd472)
```

The setups itself seem to work fine and devices can connect, send, receive, and disconnect. But with every disconnect I get the ugly above exception. Any idea what the problem could be? I am using SignalR 2.2.0 and Owin 1.2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2685) which might be fixed in v3.

Answer (score 3):

Try providing a TimeSpan to the close method to give it time to actually close while waiting for any async processes which may be in progress:

```
public void Stop()
{
    _connection.Stop(new TimeSpan(1000));
}
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This one worked for me - stopped getting websocketexceptions after adding a TimeSpan(1000) per above. Using SignalR Client 2.1.2 framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I know its lame. I am trying to shutdown signalr client when the mainwindow closes and I get a lot of exceptions that I can not catch and my process hangs. So i decided to kill the main process on form close.

```
private void OnClose(object sender, CancelEventArgs e){
        try
        {
            var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            process.Kill();
            //HubConnection.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with

```
connection.Reconnecting += connection.Stop;
```

Because I found the connection state is always reconnecting

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to stop broadcasting message when client is disconnected. So my approach is use Connection Lifetime Events in SignalR.
This is the official page : [SignalRLifeTimeEvents](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)

```
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
{
    //-- When any client will close the browser or page this event will fire

    return base.OnDisconnected();
}
```

Comment: I am not doing any special. I just use the default Stop() method on the connected SignalR client, which causes the server to throw exceptions